# Datatables within Bootstrap tabs

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-5

I have a quandary that I can't seem to resolve - any pointers would be hugely welcome.

When the tab link is clicked, the new tab opens, but the datatable within tabs 2 & 3 doesn't resize - tab1 is always ok.

I'm using datatables within boostrap tabs and the following code, which I've used on other sites and they work. This site i'm working in however, isn't playing ball - wondering if it's because it's BS5 causing a conflict ??

```
    $('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true})
        .columns.adjust()
        .responsive.recalc();
    });
```

I've also tried the code provided by Datatables, and that doesn't seem to work either - in this case. https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

I think the line

```
$.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true})
```

is not valid DataTables syntax - and I would expect it to generate an error in your browser's console:

> $.fn.dataTable.tables(...).columns is undefined

**Suggested Solutions**

You can re-write your approach in a couple of different ways (assuming you are using a recent version of DataTables).

The first two examples assume all your tables use a common CSS class name in their HTML `<table>` tags. In my case, I am using this:

```
<table id="example2" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
```

And therefore I will use the `.dataTable` class selector in the following examples.

---

**Example One**

```
$('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
  $.fn.dataTable.Api('.dataTable')
    .columns.adjust()
    .responsive.recalc();
} );
```

---

**Example Two**

```
$('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
  $('.dataTable').DataTable()
    .columns.adjust()
    .responsive.recalc();
} );
```

Note that the above example uses `DataTable()` with a capital "D".

---

**Example Three**

The above examples operate on all data tables in the page - it's just that the only one which is affected is the one you see in the selected tab.

If you want to explicitly target only one table in your tab event, you can use the approach shown in this question:

[How to make DataTable responsive in Bootstrap tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70101412/12567365)

In that answer, the approach retrieves the specific table name from a unique attribute value `'data-bs-target'` defined for each tab, for example:

```
data-bs-target="#home"
```

---

See the [API reference page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) for details.