# DataTable in tab panel not being responsive and ScrollBarX not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable, datatables

Sorry if my question sounds stupid. I am still new to front end development.

I have build two table which would be shown if tab button is clicked. However, I have problem when i set up a datatable columns are out in range of browser window, as you can see in the picture below

[Out of range table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbLrd.png)

```
<div class="page-body">

<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
</div>
<div class="card-block">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs tabs-top" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile1" role="tab">PatientProfile</a>
              <div class="slide"></div>
          </li>
         
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile2" role="tab">Treatment Record</a>
              <div class="slide"></div>
          </li>
         

      </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content tabs-left-content card-block" style="height: calc(100% - (100px)) !important; width: calc(100vw - (40px)) !important;">
          <div class="tab-pane  active" id="profile" role="tabpanel" >
              <p class="m-0">
                <div class="table-responsive dt-responsive">
                  
                  <table id="dom-jqry" class="table  table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
                   
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width:50px;">Date</th>
                      <th style="width:50px;">Dr.</th>
                      <th style="width:50px;">Trx Fee (RM)</th>
                      <th style="width:100%;">Treatment Description</th>
                    </tr>
                      <tr id="119">
                      <td>2022-05-27</td>
                      <td>Dr. Shepherd</td>
                      <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" value="150" disabled></input></td>
                      <td style="height:300px;"><textarea style="height:300px;width:100%;" disabled>Scaling and polishing </textarea></td>
                    </tr> 
                   
                  </table>
                </div>
              </p>
          </div>
        
                  
          <div class="tab-pane" id="profile2" role="tabpanel">
              <p class="m-0">
                <div class="table-responsive dt-responsive">
                  
                  <table id="dom-jqry" class="table  table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
                   
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width:50px;">Date</th>
                      <th style="width:50px;">Dr.</th>
                      <th style="width:50px;">Trx Fee (RM)</th>
                      <th style="width:100%;">Treatment Description</th>
                    </tr>
                      <tr id="119">
                      <td>2022-05-27</td>
                      <td>Dr. Medaline</td>
                      <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" value="150" disabled></input></td>
                     <td style="height:300px;"><textarea style="height:300px;width:100%;" disabled>Scaling and polishing </textarea></td>
                    </tr> 
                   
                  </table>
                </div>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Could anyone let me know how to rectify this? I would like it to be responsive and with ScrollBarX when using mobile web browser.

Comment: Have you researched the information in questions such as this: [How to make DataTable responsive in Bootstrap tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70101412/12567365) - and other similar questions?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - for example, there is no DataTable in the sample code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

please correct me if i will be wrong, before that please add this javascript code( if you are using Datatable library).

```js
var dataTable = $('#dom-jqry').DataTable({

  scrollY: "320px",
  scrollX: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  paging: true,
  pageLength: 50,

  "dom": 'Blfrtip',
  columnDefs: [{
      className: 'noVis',
    }

  ],
  "buttons": [{
    extend: 'colvis',
    columns: ':not(.noVis)'
  }],
  "processing": true,
  "ajax": {
    url: "",
    //"type" : "POST",
    "dataSrc": "",
    "data": "",
    error: function(response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
  },

  "columns": [{
    "data": "test"
  }],
  "pagingType": "full_numbers",

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.4.0/css/autoFill.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<div class="page-body">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"></div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!-- Nav tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs tabs-top" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile1" role="tab">PatientProfile</a>
              <div class="slide"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile2" role="tab">Treatment Record</a>
              <div class="slide"></div>
            </li>


          </ul>
          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content tabs-left-content card-block" style="height: calc(100% - ( 100px)) !important; width: calc(100vw - ( 40px)) !important;">
            <div class="tab-pane  active" id="profile" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="table-responsive dt-responsive">

                <table id="dom-jqry" class="table  table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Dr.</th>
                      <th>Trx Fee (RM)</th>
                      <th>Treatment Description</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr id="119">
                      <td>2022-05-27</td>
                      <td>Dr. Shepherd</td>
                      <td><input type="text" value="150" disabled></td>
                      <td><textarea disabled>Scaling and polishing </textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>

                </table>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="tab-pane" id="profile2" role="tabpanel">
              <p class="m-0">
                <div class="table-responsive dt-responsive">

                  <table id="dom-jqry1" class="table  table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">

                    <tr>
                      <th style="width: 50px;">Date</th>
                      <th style="width: 50px;">Dr.</th>
                      <th style="width: 50px;">Trx Fee (RM)</th>
                      <th style="width: 100%;">Treatment Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="119">
                      <td>2022-05-27</td>
                      <td>Dr. Medaline</td>
                      <td><input type="text" style="width: 50px;" value="150" disabled></input>
                      </td>
                      <td style="height: 300px;"><textarea style="height: 300px; width: 100%;" disabled>Scaling and polishing </textarea></td>
                    </tr>

                  </table>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.4.0/js/dataTables.autoFill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

you can hereby modify as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add a responsive option inside your DataTables options with a boolean value.

```
$('#dom-jqry').DataTable( {
responsive: true
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `style="width:100%;"` from table tag